# How to select Date between Two date?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I want to select date between (System date - 2 hour ) to (system date)

Comment: You've tagged as oracle but wrote you want select in Java. What do yuo want to do?

Comment: Why all those tags? Java, Oracle, xml, ... ? Also, what is the problem?

Comment: Select statement where date between (current system date - two hours and to current system date) , please help

Comment: What '(current system date - two hours and to current system date)' means?
Please check your question again

Comment: @Kedar1442 I want to select statement between ("current date - 2hour") to (current date)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this for selecting records in the last two hours and it works.

```
#SQL Server
 SELECT
      *
 FROM
      table
 WHERE
      datetime_col >= DATEADD(hh, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 AND
      datetime_col <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I'm less familiar with Oracle but here is a possible solution I found online.

```
#oracle
SELECT
     *
FROM
     table
WHERE
     datetime_col BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - 1/24 AND LOCALTIMESTAMP
```

[Oracle Forum: Find record count between two time stamps](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1074856?start=0&tstart=0)